# XML serialize object into different output format

Tags: xml, vb.net, xslt, xml-serialization

I'm using `XmlSerializer` and `XmlType / XmlAttribute` attributes to serialize and deserialize XML to a container object.

Input XML:

```
 <row identifier="blah" firstname="blah" lastname="blah" />
```

And the object:

```
<Serializable(), XmlType("row")> _
Public Class RowEmployee
    <XmlAttribute("identifier")> _
    Public EmployeeIdentifier As String

    <XmlAttribute("firstname")> _
    Public FirstName As String

    <XmlAttribute("middlename")> _
    Public MiddleName As String

    <XmlAttribute("lastname")> _
    Public LastName As String

End Class
```

This approach is nice and clean / simple, matches the input XML format and will translate to and from XML just fine, the only problem is that my output XML is slightly different in format, e.g.

```
 <employee Identifier="blah" FirstName="blah" .....>
```

I don't have much experience with XSLT, but I'm kind of assuming that would be the way to go with this.  Are there any other approaches that would be simpler than XSLT, given this sort of setup?

Also, if anyone knows of any good resources for a "crash course" on using XSLT with .NET in a similar context, that would be very greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re: @afrogonabike's answer, yes, I did have a container class I glossed over for the deserialization to an object:

```
<Serializable(), XmlRoot("data"), XmlType("data")> _
Public Class AesopEmployeeCollection
    <XmlElement("row")> _
    Public Employees As List(Of AesopEmployee)

    Public Sub New()
        Me.Employees = New List(Of AesopEmployee)()
    End Sub

    Public Function GetEmployeeInfo(AesopId As String) As AesopEmployee
        Return (From e In Employees Where e.EmployeeIdentifier = AesopId).FirstOrDefault()
    End Function
End Class
```

I did end up going with XSLT, and the transform was actually fairly straightforward:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="row">
    <employees>
        <employee>
            <xsl:attribute name="Identifier">
                <xsl:value-of select="@identifier" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="FirstName">
                <xsl:value-of select="@firstname" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <!-- dont send middlename if blank -->
            <xsl:if test="string-length(@middlename)!=0">
               <xsl:attribute name="MiddleName">
                   <xsl:value-of select="@middlename" />
               </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>  
            <xsl:attribute name="LastName">
                 <xsl:value-of select="@lastname" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            ......
        </employee>
    </employees>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The serialization / transformation logic wasn't too bad either:

```
        Dim Ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
        Dim Xslt As New XslCompiledTransform()
        Xslt.Load(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/MyRoot/Xslt/EmployeeInfo.xslt"))

        Using Xtw As New System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(Ms, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
            SharedInfo.EmpSerializer.Serialize(Xtw, RowEmp)
            Ms = DirectCast(Xtw.BaseStream, System.IO.MemoryStream)
            Ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
            Dim XmlReader As New XmlTextReader(Ms)
            Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
            Dim WriterSettings As New XmlWriterSettings()
            WriterSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = True
            Using XmlWriter As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sb, WriterSettings)
                Xslt.Transform(XmlReader, XmlWriter)
                Dim XmlResponse = EmpImportService.AddOrUpdate(sb.ToString(), ServiceApiKey)

                For Each ResponseNode As XmlNode In XmlResponse.ChildNodes
                    ResponseMessage.Append("<li>").Append(ResponseNode.Attributes("message").Value).Append("</li>")
                Next
            End Using
        End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want each RowEmployee class to be serialized as a "row" element in the xml?  You will need to specify this as the ElementName where this class is used eg:

```
[XmlElement("row")]
public rows As List(Of RowEmployee)
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  I glossed over the container class for these employees, and apparently I'm a dunce at mini-Markdown.  See my answer below.